# Use GetParam() in SetUpTestCase

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a parameterized test in which I use the *SetUpTestCase()* function, like this:

```
class SimulationTest : public ::testing::TestWithParam<SimulationTestParameters> {
    public:
    static void SetUpTestCase() {
----->   SimulationTestParameters params = GetParam();
         ...
    }
    .... more code ... 
}
```

I want to call the *GetParam()* function from there, but since *SetUpTestCase()* is static, I get this error:

> Cannot call member function ' ... GetParam() ... ' without object:
>       SimulationTestParameters params = GetParam();
>       _____________________________________ ^

Is there no way to **access the parameters from a static function**?
I also tried to get the parameter value in a standart constructor, but then the static function can't access the non-static variable set in the constructor.

Any help would be appreciated.

Best,
Romeo

Comment: Since the parameter is stored in an instance of the fixture you'll need a pointer or reference to an instance of `SimulationTest` in order to access it. Do you have a pointer or reference to an instance of `SimulationTest`?

Comment: No, I later just call 'INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(...);'

Comment: just remove `static`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not doing what you want to do.

SetupTestCase is static because it is called once per *test fixture*, thus it wouldn't make any sense to be able to get the invidual test case paramater from there.

Setup is called once per *test*, thus you can call GetParam from there as it is run for a specific test case.